# Fill ggplot barchart variable's category to alternate colour by variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with values, for variables, with each categorized into 3 observation categories.

Below is a minimum working example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
Test.df <-c()
Test.df$Value <- runif(51)
Test.df <- as.data.frame(Test.df)
Test.df$Category <- as.factor(c("A", "B", "C"))
Test.df <- arrange(Test.df, Category)
Test.df$Variable <- c("ZA", "ZB", "ZC", "ZD", "ZE", "ZF", "ZF", "ZH", "ZI", "ZJ", "ZK", "ZL", "ZM", "ZN", "ZO", "ZP", "ZQ")

Colors <- c("#E8223D","#E4B533","#4BA046","#C7202F","#EF402C","#27BFE5","#FBC413","#A21C43","#F26A2D","#DE1768","#F99D29","#BF8D2C","#407F46","#1E97D4","#5ABA47","#136A9F","#15496B")

Bar.Plot <-
  ggplot(Test.df, aes(x = Variable, y = Value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",
           width = 0.9,
           position = position_dodge(width = 1), 
           aes(fill = Category)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(Test.df$Variable, values=Colors)

Bar.Plot
```

This outputs the following plot:

[image: example plot]

How can the colors alternate by variable, so that variable ZA's 3 observations are the same color, variable ZB's 3 observations are the next color, and each variable iterates down the list for colors?

Additionally, is it possible to add an alpha for each observation to add some transparency e.g. to have a different alpha for each of the three ZA observations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides fill, there is also the group aesthetic:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)

Test.df <- c()
Test.df$Value <- runif(51)
Test.df <- as.data.frame(Test.df)
Test.df$Category <- as.factor(c("A", "B", "C"))
Test.df <- arrange(Test.df, Category)
Test.df$Variable <- c("ZA", "ZB", "ZC", "ZD", "ZE", "ZF", "ZF", "ZH", "ZI", "ZJ", "ZK", "ZL", "ZM", "ZN", "ZO", "ZP", "ZQ")

Colors <- c("#E8223D", "#E4B533", "#4BA046", "#C7202F", "#EF402C", "#27BFE5", "#FBC413", "#A21C43", "#F26A2D", "#DE1768", "#F99D29", "#BF8D2C", "#407F46", "#1E97D4", "#5ABA47", "#136A9F", "#15496B")


Bar.Plot <-
  ggplot(Test.df, aes(x = Variable, y = Value)) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity",
    width = 0.9,
    position = position_dodge(width = 1),
    aes(fill = Variable, group = Category, alpha = Category)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(Test.df$Variable, values = Colors) +
  guides(alpha = FALSE)
#> Warning: `guides(<scale> = FALSE)` is deprecated. Please use `guides(<scale> =
#> "none")` instead.

Bar.Plot
#> Warning: Using alpha for a discrete variable is not advised.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much for the help danloo.

You've addressed the first question, and that has been helpful.

For the alpha, my questions was not detailed enough.

Is it possible to add an increasing alpha within each variable, i.e.: variable ZA observation 1 has alpha of 1, obs. 2 has alpha of .9, and obs. 3 has alpha of .8? This would then be applied to each variable.

Comment: @Methos I revised the question and the answer

Comment: Thank again for another stab at the issue, but it seems there is still a misunderstanding.

It seems from looking at your application, alpha should be set to "Category" in order to address the issue.

Thanks for the help, I was not aware of all of these settings.

Comment: Is it possible to change the order of the alpha?

Comment: Yes. Just set factor levels of column Category accordingly. ggplot will always consider the order of factor levels for position and transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Following `danloo`'s solution added `scale_alpha_discrete(guide=FALSE)`

```
    library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)

Test.df <- c()
Test.df$Value <- runif(51)
Test.df <- as.data.frame(Test.df)
Test.df$Category <- as.factor(c("A", "B", "C"))
Test.df <- arrange(Test.df, Category)
Test.df$Variable <- c("ZA", "ZB", "ZC", "ZD", "ZE", "ZF", "ZF", "ZH", "ZI", "ZJ", "ZK", "ZL", "ZM", "ZN", "ZO", "ZP", "ZQ")

Colors <- c("#E8223D", "#E4B533", "#4BA046", "#C7202F", "#EF402C", "#27BFE5", "#FBC413", "#A21C43", "#F26A2D", "#DE1768", "#F99D29", "#BF8D2C", "#407F46", "#1E97D4", "#5ABA47", "#136A9F", "#15496B")

Bar.Plot <-
  ggplot(Test.df, aes(x = Variable, y = Value)) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity",
    width = 0.9,
   
    position = position_dodge(width = 1),
    aes(fill = Variable, group = Category,  alpha = Category)
  ) +
  scale_alpha_discrete(guide=FALSE)
```

[image]